# self in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
-(void)setFaceView:(FaceView *)faceView  
{
_faceView= faceView;
self.faceView.dataSource = self;
}
```

I just started learning IOS programming with famous Stanford lectures on iTunes. I am currently at lecture 6 and I start to have difficulty catching up with the class.

It is a really basic thing, but I really don't understand how 'self' works. Can anyone teach me what 'self's in this code are doing?

Comment: Do you know any other object-oriented languages?  For a first approximation `self` in Objective-C is the same as `this` in Java or C++.

Comment: We are only supposed to be on lecture 2/assignment 1 right now. Even outside of that, you might get better answers from the rest of us on piazza.

Comment: Thanks Hot Licks for your advice, but I never actually implemented Java or C++.

Comment: Don't worry, most programmers haven't *implemented* Java or C++ either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self` is an implicit parameter in objective-c of instance methods that refers to the object performing the method - see here: [Messages to Self and Super](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-89660)

In this case, `self.faceView` is a call to the property accessor for faceView that is bound to the instance that runs this method, while the assignment `_faceView= faceView;`  is assigning the input parameter `faceView` to the iVar `_faceView`. `self.faceView.dataSource = self;` assigns the object performing this method to the `dataSource` property of the object's `faceView` property.

Answer (score 1):

self is the object itself. when you alloc an object. it sets aside enough memory to hold all the variables that class will use.

when you init the object however you attach that memory to self. self is essentially a "variable" (and i use the term loosely) that gives you access to all the functions of the object you are within.

if you have an object with the following method

```
+(BOOL) isThisWorking{ return YES;}
```

you would have to call the method on the class. Self is not involved.

however if you have a method

```
-(BOOL) isThisWorking{ return YES; }
```

then you would have a method attached to an instance of a class.

calling the first one would require you to call it on the class object itself.

```
[MyObject isThisWorking];
```

calling the second one would require you to call it on an instance.

```
MyObject *testObject = [[MyObject alloc] init];
[testObject isThisWorking];
```

when you are in a method within test object you will not have the 'testObject' to call methods on.

self fills that void.

if you come from another programming language you will be familiar with other constructs that do the same thing.

for instance in .net the object is "this"

and in old school vb if i remember correctly the object is "Me"